# Is it possible to use a constant as the property name in routerLink's queryParams?

Tags: angular, typescript, query-string, angular-routerlink, angular12

I'm trying to navigate to the current page and change/add the query parameter "categoryId".  If I do:

```
<a
      [routerLink]=""
      [queryParams]="{ categoryId: category!.id }"
      queryParamsHandling="merge"
>
```

It works fine, but I have a constant for the query param name, that way if I ever want to change it, I don't have to find every instance.

In the component.ts, I have the property:

```
categoryIdQueryParamName = QueryParamNames.CATEGORY_ID;
```

I have tried:

```
<a
  [routerLink]=""
  [queryParams]="{ {{'"' + categoryIdQueryParamName + '"' }}: category!.id }"
  queryParamsHandling="merge"
>
```

After looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/787958,
I tried:

```
<a
  [routerLink]=""
  [queryParams]="{ [categoryIdQueryParamName]: category!.id }"
  queryParamsHandling="merge"
>
```

But, I'm still getting a compile error.  If possible, what is the correct way to do this?  Side note, I know I could do this programmatically with `(click)`, but I am utilizing `<a [routerLink]>` to get the benefit of being able to right-click and open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanest way is to do it in ts

```
public get queryParams() {
    const p = {};
    p[QueryParamNames.CATEGORY_ID] = category!.id;
    return p;
}

<a [routerLink]="" [queryParams]="queryParams" queryParamsHandling="merge" >
```

Comment: That works and is a very clean approach!  One note, for strict TS to allow this, I had to do: `const p: Params = {};`.